# Render a different view script, pass data to that view and get output in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, action, render

I want to render a `different` view in my `action`, pass data from action to that view and get its output in a variable.

I know that

```
  $output = $this->view->render('path/to/script');
```

render different view script and returns output. But I also want to pass data to this script from my action but not succeeded so far. I have used

```
 $this->view->data = $data
```

But it doesn't send data to this script.

Can any one guide how can I do it?

Comment: (OOT) Just a note, to render not default view script `$this->renderScript('report/app-list-xlsx.tpl');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an array of data to the view script:

```
$this->view->render('path/to/script/script', array('someValue' => true));
```

Access it in the view script with:

```
<?= $this->someValue ?>
```

EDIT:
In a controller I always use...

```
$this->view->assign('someValue', 'data');
```

EDIT: With layout pattern...
You need to set a variable in the controller for the path of the view script you want to use in the layout template and any variables/data you want passing to the view partial.

In controller:

```
$this->view->assign('partialPath', 'path/to/partial');
$this->view->assign('partialdata', 'value');
```

In Layout:

```
$this->view->render($this->partialPath, $this->partialData) //renders partial and passes data
```

In partial:

```
<?= $this->partialData ?> // echos data
```

Comment: $htmlcontent = $this->view->render('scorecard/pdfpage5.phtml',array('data'=>$data)); at controller doesn't pass data. Tried to get as `$this->data`;

Comment: Are you using MVC pattern with a layout?

Comment: Yes with layout pattern